# Strange Git Error on Docker NPM Install

Tags: node.js, git, docker, dockerfile, npm-install

I had a working Dockerfile until literally a day ago when it just seemed to break. I didn't make any changes to my dependencies - but I am getting the following error:

```
[91mnpm ERR! code ENOGIT
[0m
[91mnpm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR! 
npm[0m
[91m ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
[0m
[91m
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-09-28T21_12_50_050Z-debug.log
[0m
Removing intermediate container be9d5bfe5521

The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This is super strange because this wasn't happening before. I'm also attaching my Dockerfile. The things I've tried so far are adding git (third line), and also trying to export the path. Nothing seems to be working.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git

FROM node:alpine

RUN npm install sails -g
#RUN npm install git -g
#RUN export PATH="$HOME/usr/bin/git:$PATH"

RUN mkdir -p /service/app
WORKDIR /service/app

COPY package.json /service/app
RUN npm install

COPY . /service/app

EXPOSE 80

CMD NODE_ENV=production sails lift
```

Comment: Add `ENV NODE_DEBUG=fs,module,http,https` at the top of your dockerfile. This will show a lots of log but you might get hold of the actual issue

Comment: @aamirl were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

One reason for this could be that you are using the slim version of node in your `Dockerfile`:

`FROM node:8-slim`

I presume this does not include git, because when I changed to the full version the error went away:

`FROM node:8.11.2`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It was due to lack of git. Below is how it worked

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN apk add git
RUN npm install ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --update git && \
    apk add --update openssh
```

The git binary within the docker container becomes available at `/usr/bin/git`

Answer (score 0):

I know this was an old question but I noticed none of the answers addressed the root cause of your problem even though adding `RUN apk add git` can fix it in the end.

In your Dockerfile, you have **two** FROM, but apparently, you did not use it them for [Multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/), which means you did it wrong. Your adding git clause has no use there (your first from related clauses have no use too.).

Adding git clause should be added to the second from clause, `FROM node:alpine` and for alpine, it should use `apk add` not `apt-get install` (that is for ubuntu)